# Flutter display data from List once if data is repeated

Tags: flutter, dart

I am fetching data from a database, and let's say the fetched data then return a list which contains `List fetchedData = [2, 4, 6, 1, 2, 5, 2]`, I then want to display the data with a `ListView.builder` as so

```
return ListView.builder(
    itemCount: fetchedData.length,
    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
      return Text(
        fetchedData[index],
      );
    },
  ),
```

But the list contains the number `2` more than once, so the number 2 would in this case be displayed three times, but I would only want to display it once, is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to create a Set from your list, like

```
var fetchedSet = Set.from(fetchedData);
```

then iterate like

```
return Text(
fetchedSet.elementAt(index)
);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, so it does work but I get this error `The following IndexError was thrown building:
RangeError (index): Index out of range: index should be less than 5: 5`

Comment: reset your itemCount to the length of the set instead of the original list